# Androidx AppCompatButton looks different from Button even on high API Level device

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, androidx, material-components-android

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton)

> A Button which supports compatible features on older versions of the
>   platform, including:
>
> Allows dynamic tint of its background via the background tint methods
>   in ViewCompat. Allows setting of the background tint using
>   R.attr.backgroundTint and R.attr.backgroundTintMode. This will
>   automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts and the
>   top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only
>   need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Now, this makes me assume that the following two buttons would look exactly the same on high level devices.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:text="AppCompatButton"
        android:id="@+id/appcompatbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:layout_below="@id/appcompatbutton"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

However, here is how it actually looks:

[image]

I ran this on the following emulator:
Galaxy Nexus, API:28 (720 x 1280 xhdpi)

And when I apply buttonStyle in my appTheme like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
</style>
```

It changes the AppCompatButton but not the normal button like this:
(Note the slight difference in the rounded edges)

[image]

I also tried to create a custom button that both inherited from android.widget.Button and also androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton, both of these buttons show the same behaviour as using AppCompatButton in xml does. So it feels like the only outlier is Button in XML.

Question 1:

This all seems incredibly confusing according to me. Can someone clarify this as either a bug or feature?

**EDIT 1**

Doing debugging I found that the Button actually gets transformed into a MaterialButton, see the following:
[image]

Question 2:

Why is this transformation happening?

**EDIT 2**

Question 2 answer:

The transformation of Button to MaterialButton is due to the parent theme I was using.

Question 3:

How do you implement a custom button which works just like Button in xml would?

As a side note and personal opinion, also a slight repetition, this system is not only confusing but its hard to get it right and foolproof for future changes. In addition to this, the documentation is very poor. I would appreciate if an answer to this would be included as well, or at least a discussion regarding it, how to deal with it for example.

Comment: i usually just set a background drawable to my buttons to ensure they always look the same, i usually do the drawable via xml code though, there you can set the colors you want and the rounded edges

Comment: I have been complaining to google about the Theme/Style/Attributes engine since late 2012. The answer has been complete silence until around 2017 when they said: "yeah... we gotta focus on discoverability" in a reddit AMA. Then they released all the Material Design libraries, but the Android one was so incomplete (still is) that it was kind of a joke. Fast forwards to 2019... they kept the whole thing (Material 2.0), it's still incomplete, but now Android Studio (3.5 maybe?) should help you find "where your stuff comes from". So...yes, the system is awful.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for that answer, it doesn't solve the problem at hand but it does provide me, and others, with the comfort that they are not alone with the issue.

Comment: @LudvigW Good question! Maybe it is late to answer. I've just tried to explain all points, with examples and links to the current code. And yes, it is not simple to get all the info about components and styles. No problem to discuss each point if is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answers.**

> This all seems incredibly confusing according to me. Can someone clarify this as either a bug or feature?

They use different styles.

> Why is this transformation happening?

There is an auto-inflation enabled which will replace `<Button` with `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` at runtime.

> How do you implement a custom button which works just like Button in xml would?

You can customize the attributes in xml or the theme attributes.

**Long answers.**

1. **They use different styles.**

The default style of `MaterialButton` is `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`.
This style inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Button` but changes some attributes.
[Here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L25) you can find the differences.

The main difference [is here](http://%3Citem%20name=%22shapeAppearance%22%3E?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent%3C/item%3E):

```
<item name="shapeAppearance">?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent</item>
```

You can read more about shaping in the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).
If you navigate through the style you will find:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/mtrl_shape_corner_size_small_component</item>
  </style>
```

where `mtrl_shape_corner_size_small_component` = `4dp`.
It explains the slight difference in the rounded edges.

Also you are using 
`<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>`.

It doesn't work for the MaterialButton. You have to use:

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
```

2. The **auto-inflation** is [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java#L57).

The `MaterialComponentsViewInflater` replaces some framework widgets with Material Components ones at inflation time, provided a Material Components theme is in use.
Something similar happens also with AppCompat (you can check that `MaterialComponentsViewInflater extends AppCompatViewInflater`).

It means that, the `<Button` is replaced `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` at runtime, if you are using a Material Theme.

3. **There are different options**. One of these is to define a custom style for buttons.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name="cornerRadius">xxx</item>
</style>
```

or

```
  <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/SShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">xxdp</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `<Button>` to `<ImageButton>`

Quick and short way.

Don't forget to check & change references in java/kotlin files. Compiler will alert you any way.